# How do I properly configure conditional actions with user input in VBS with MsgBox?

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting, runtime-error, msgbox

I have been trying to get a VBS script to work for a while now with msgbox. When I use a single msgbox statement, it works. As soon as I start adding conditional input options, then it doesn't work.

I posted this question on Super User and I was told to use the "dim" statement, and to post on this website, and I have done both now. Here is some of the code I am trying that works. (Please ignore my example.)

```
Option Explicit
Dim vbsmsg, vbsyes, vbsno
vbsmsg=MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed?", 1+48, "Format Drive C:")
```

When I run the above code via a shortcut I get a dialog like this:
[image]

But if I add the following, I get a run-time error when clicking "OK" or "Cancel"

```
If vbsmsg=1 Then
    vbsyes=MsgBox("The contents of your C: Drive could not be successfully deleted.", 0+64, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 5")
If vbsmsg=2 Then
    vbsno=MsgBox("Not all of the contents of your C: Drive were successfully deleted. Please try again.", 0+64, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 303")
```

[image]

The line/character in the error is between the "0" and "3" in "System Error 303"

I have tried a great deal of troubleshooting already. I have tried altering the dim statement, adding option explicit, using 1 and 2 instead of 6 and 8, etc... nothing seems to work. When I commented out the 2nd part, instead of getting an error after executing the file, it just closed on me. I am positive all of my syntax is correct and in the right format. I changed 1 and 2 to vbOK and vbCancel and when I changed it back it wouldn't work at all and gave me the error pictured on this page right away.

If anyone knows what is wrong with my examples, I would greatly appreciate it. I am fairly new to working with VBS files, but I have been working with .bat files for a long time and none of those principles seem to be working here,

I would appreciate any assistance, even if it is small,

Comment: If you write an If-statement on more than one line, like you did, then you have to use End If.  Review the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried adding EndIf, it just gave me a different error

Comment: @HansPassant could have used ` _` after the `Then` to avoid the need for `End If`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this example a try:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Question
Title = "user input in VBS with MsgBox"
Question = MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed ?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion, Title)
If Question = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "We proceed wipping your C:\ drive",vbExclamation,Title
    'Call your sub here to continue proceeding your script
Else
    MsgBox "Canceling the operation !",vbCritical,Title
    Wscript.Quit()
End If
```

For more information about **[MsgBox Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1ft6yf3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)**

Comment: Just one question after running this, you know how I had the 1+48 in my original VBS script? Where would that go in this new version now that it is not on one line? Right now, I get the ? icon when opening, the Caution icon if clicking yes, and the critical icon if clicking "No".

Comment: It doesn't really explain why @InterLinked was getting `Expected 'End'` compilation error. Adding the named constants doesn't fix that but I agree they should be used, the issue was `If` statement spanning multiple lines without an `End If` or continuation character `_`.

Answer (score 1):

While [@Hackoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080770/hackoo) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36553879/692942) is technically correct it doesn't answer the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36553287/1), so I'll attempt to here.

The reason for the error

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected 'End'

is due to the `If` statement spanning more then one line without an `End If` to finish the statement block, as in [@Hackoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080770/hackoo) example adding `End If` will correct this error.

If for whatever reason you wanted to keep the syntax condensed you weren't far away you had two options;

1. Put the `If` statements all on one line

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Dim vbsmsg
   vbsmsg = MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Format Drive C:")

   If vbsmsg = vbYes Then Call MsgBox("The contents of your C: Drive could not be successfully deleted.", vbExclamation, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 5")
   If vbsmsg = vbNo Then Call MsgBox("Not all of the contents of your C: Drive were successfully deleted. Please try again.", vbCritical, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 303")
   ```

   which can be a little ugly looking at sometimes hard to follow *(but that's just my opinion)*.
2. Use the Line Continuation Character *(`_`)* to allow a single statement to span multiple lines, in VBScript this is also known as a [Statement Break](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198844.aspx).

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Dim vbsmsg
   vbsmsg = MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Format Drive C:")

   If vbsmsg = vbYes Then _
       Call MsgBox("The contents of your C: Drive could not be successfully deleted.", vbExclamation, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 5")
   If vbsmsg = vbNo Then _
       Call MsgBox("Not all of the contents of your C: Drive were successfully deleted. Please try again.", vbCritical, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 303")
   ```

As already mentioned it goes without saying that you should endeavour to use the VBScript Named Constants in code wherever possible instead of hard coded numeric values.

Comment: Wow, quick up-vote then down-vote...do the examples not work, did I not answer the question?

Comment: And how did you know if the OP downvote or other person ? and why the person who downovote don't let a message to explain why ??

Comment: Thank you for the info and you deserve from me +1 ;)

Comment: @Hackoo I apologise it seems it was someone else, now I feel terrible.